# EOFException java.io.EOFException in Talend after x Records

Tags: java, talend

I created a Talend job which does this: 
Read record x from table A. Write record x + 1.000.000 in table A.
This works great, but fails after 310 records.
It clearly has notthing to do with the values in the records.
If I alter the input query with X >= 1 and X <= 300,  and after running succesfully without errors, alter it to X >= 301 and X <= 600, it runs again succesfully without any errors. But if X >= 1 and X <= 600, it stops after 310 records. I have to do thousands of records, so changing my query every 310 records is not an option.

I tried to alter the "commit after" from 10.000 to 100, 10 even 1, but that doesn't help.

What can I do?

```
    java.io.EOFExceptionException in component tJDBCOutput_1
java.sql.SQLException: java.io.EOFException
    at com.kewill.jdbc.JdbcUnimsConnection.sendMessage(JdbcUnimsConnection.java:182)
    at com.kewill.jdbc.JdbcUnimsConnection.commit(JdbcUnimsConnection.java:255)
    at local_project.tsdsmd_0_1.tsdsmd.tJDBCInput_1Process(tsdsmd.java:12790)
    at local_project.tsdsmd_0_1.tsdsmd.runJobInTOS(tsdsmd.java:13237)
    at local_project.tsdsmd_0_1.tsdsmd.main(tsdsmd.java:13036)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at com.kewill.jdbc.JdbcUnimsSocket.readFully(JdbcUnimsSocket.java:170)
    at com.kewill.jdbc.JdbcUnimsMessage.init(JdbcUnimsMessage.java:114)
    at com.kewill.jdbc.JdbcUnimsMessage.<init>(JdbcUnimsMessage.java:96)
    at com.kewill.jdbc.JdbcUnimsSocket.readMessage(JdbcUnimsSocket.java:122)
    at com.kewill.jdbc.JdbcUnimsSocket.sendMessage(JdbcUnimsSocket.java:106)
    at com.kewill.jdbc.JdbcUnimsSocket.sendMessage(JdbcUnimsSocket.java:89)
    at com.kewill.jdbc.JdbcUnimsConnection.sendMessage(JdbcUnimsConnection.java:166)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by asking more questions.

Questions. How much memory is allocated to the Talend job?  Have you turned on debug level logging in Log4j ? Do you have the latest version of the JDBC driver?  Can you use the same driver and query in a  SQL tool, How long does it take to Return 10 results, 300 results, all the results? Does the driver have a setting for the timeout value?

Comment: A lot of questions :)
Memory Xms:256,Xmx1024
Debug level logging in Log4j? I don't have that option in Talend, I think.
I don't have another SQL tool installed. Which do you prefer?
300 results within 3 seconds.
As far as I know, there is no timeout value setting in de the driver.

Comment: The initial exception appears to be happening in the JDBC driver. So... it it really important to try the same query in a SQL Tool, such as "Execute Query" (http://executequery.org/index.php),  using the most up to date version of the JDBC Driver for your data source.    If the query doesn't work in a SQL Tool using your JDBC driver, the problem isn't Talend.